# Android-Recycler view is not appearing just in android 7.0

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I was testing my app on many device and it was working fine...Untill I tested on an android device running android 7.1 the recycler view is gone while it exists on other devices tahte my Code:

RecyclerGridLayoutAdapter:

```
public class RecyclerGridLayoutAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerGridLayoutAdapter.ViewHolder>{

  private int resource;
        private ArrayList<Item> contacts;
    private TreeMap<String,ArrayList<Contact>> gridsMap;
    private String searchedString;
    private Context activity;
    private String myNumber;

    public RecyclerGridLayoutAdapter(int resource, ArrayList<Item> contacts,Context activity) {
        this.resource = resource;
        this.contacts = contacts;
        this.activity=activity;

        gridsMap= DatabaseHandler.getDataBaseHandler(activity).getContactsByAlphabets();
        loadData();

        searchedString="";

    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v;
        v= LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(resource,parent,false);
        ViewHolder vh=new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Log.wtf("begin ","inserting "+contacts.get(position).type);
        if(contacts.get(position).type==0){
            holder.header.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.header.setText(contacts.get(position).alphabet);
            holder.name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else {
            holder.header.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            SharedPreferences prefs=activity.getSharedPreferences("myNumber",0);
            final String myNumber=prefs.getString("number","not pund");

            holder.name.setText(contacts.get(position).contact.name);
            if(contacts.get(position).contact.isRegistered.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                holder.image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.contact_offline_pic);

                holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent=new Intent(activity, ChatRoomActivity.class);
                        AppMasterManager.activity=ChatRoomActivity.class;
                        intent.putExtra("room",contacts.get(position).contact.room);
                        intent.putExtra("contact_name",contacts.get(position).contact.name);
                        intent.putExtra("myNumber",myNumber);
                        if (contacts.get(position).contact.isPrivate.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                            if (!DatabaseHandler.getDataBaseHandler(activity).numberExist(contacts.get(position).contact.phone_number)){
                                DatabaseHandler.getDataBaseHandler(activity).addPrivateContact(contacts.get(position).contact);
                                try {
                                    ChatService.bind.getService().joinANumber(contacts.get(position).contact);
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            intent.putExtra("account", Accounts.SECONDARY_ACCOUNT);
                        }else {
                            intent.putExtra("account", Accounts.PRIMARY_ACCOUNT);
                        }
                        Log.wtf("from grid adapter inflater",contacts.get(position).contact.room);
                        activity.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });


                if(contacts.get(position).contact.state.equalsIgnoreCase("offline")){
                    holder.image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.contact_offline_pic);
                }
                else {
                    holder.image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.contact_online_pic);
                }
            }
            else {


                holder.image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.contact_unregistered_pic);

            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contacts.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView header;
        public TextView name;
        public ImageView image;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            header=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.first_char_header);
            name=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
            image=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_grid_contact);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
      if(contacts.get(position).type==0){
          return 4;
      }
      else {
          return 1;
      }

    }


        public void search(String pattern){

        searchedString=pattern;
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(pattern)) {
            searchedString=pattern;
            gridsMap.clear();
           gridsMap=DatabaseHandler.getDataBaseHandler(activity).getContactsByAlphabetsWithPattern(pattern);

            contacts.clear();
            loadData();


        }
        else {
            gridsMap.clear();
            gridsMap=DatabaseHandler.getDataBaseHandler(activity).getContactsByAlphabets();

            contacts.clear();
            loadData();
        }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void updateDataSet(){

            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(searchedString)){

                contacts.clear();
                gridsMap.clear();
                gridsMap=DatabaseHandler.getDataBaseHandler(activity).getContactsByAlphabetsWithPattern(searchedString);
                loadData();

                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
            else {
                contacts.clear();
                gridsMap.clear();
                gridsMap=DatabaseHandler.getDataBaseHandler(activity).getContactsByAlphabets();

                loadData();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        void loadData(){
            for(String c:gridsMap.keySet()){
                contacts.add(new Item(0,c));
                Log.wtf("add","+");

                for(Contact d:gridsMap.get(c)){
                    contacts.add(new Item(1,c,d));

                }}
        }



        public void searchOnline(final String pattern) throws JSONException {



                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(pattern)){
                    JSONObject object=new JSONObject();
                    object.put("pattern",pattern);
                    JsonObjectRequest request_json = new JsonObjectRequest(WebServiceApi.SEARCH_SECONDARY_CONTACTS_ONLINE,object, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                if(response.getJSONArray("res").length()>0){
                                    contacts.clear();
                                    Log.w("result ",response.getJSONArray("res").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("secondary_account").getString("user_name").toString());

                                    contacts.add(new Item(0,pattern.toCharArray()[0]+""));
                                    for(int i=0;i<response.getJSONArray("res").length();i++){
                                        String name=response.getJSONArray("res").getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("secondary_account").getString("user_name");
                                        String phone_number=response.getJSONArray("res").getJSONObject(i).getString("phone_number");
                                        String room;
                                        if(phone_number.compareTo(myNumber)>0){
                                           room=phone_number+myNumber;
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            room=myNumber+phone_number;
                                        }
                                        Contact contact=new Contact();
                                        contact.name=name;
                                        contact.room=room;
                                        contact.phone_number=phone_number;
                                        contact.isRegistered="true";
                                        contact.state="offline";
                                        contact.isPrivate="true";

                                        contacts.add(new Item(1,pattern.toCharArray()[0]+"",contact));

                                    }


                                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                                else{
                                    contacts.clear();
                                    loadData();
                                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            VolleyLog.d("No Activity", error.getMessage());

                        }
                    });

                    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request_json);
                }
                else {
                    contacts.clear();
                    loadData();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
        }

        public void setNumber(String number){
            myNumber=number;
        }
}
```

ContactsFragement:

```
public class ContactsFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnContactsFragementInteraction mListener;
    private RecyclerView listContacts;
    private GridLayoutManager manager;
    private HashMap<String,Contact> roomMaps;
    private String number;
    private boolean isLoaded=false;
    private RecyclerGridLayoutAdapter adapter;

    public ContactsFragment() {

    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment ContactsFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static ContactsFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        ContactsFragment fragment = new ContactsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mListener.pressed();
        if(savedInstanceState==null){Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"First Time running this fragment",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
            roomMaps = new HashMap<>();
            listContacts = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list_contacts);

        EditText contact_search_box = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_box_contacts);
            contact_search_box.clearFocus();
            number = this.getArguments().getString("number");
//            contactsListAdapter = new ContactsListAdapterAlternative(getActivity(), new ArrayList<GridLayoutAdapter>(), R.layout.list_contacts_item);
//            listContacts.setAdapter(contactsListAdapter);

               manager=new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),4);
        manager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                return (adapter.getItemViewType(position));

            }
        });
               adapter=new RecyclerGridLayoutAdapter(R.layout.list_contacts_item,new ArrayList<Item>(),getActivity());
               adapter.setNumber(number);
        manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);




            listContacts.setLayoutManager(manager);
            listContacts.setHasFixedSize(true);

            listContacts.setAdapter(adapter);

            EditText search_online_box=getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_online);

        search_online_box.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                try {
                    adapter.searchOnline(s.toString());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });


            contact_search_box.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    adapter.search(charSequence.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                }

            });
            isLoaded=true;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnContactsFragementInteraction) {
            mListener = (OnContactsFragementInteraction) context;
            mListener.pressed();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }


    public void updateState(String room,HashMap<String,String> map) {
               if(adapter!=null)
               adapter.updateDataSet();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }



    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnContactsFragementInteraction {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void pressed();
        ChatService getService();
        void setRoutablity(boolean routablity);
    }





}
```

fragment_contacts:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/contactsFragment"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/topSearchBar"
            android:weightSum="2">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/search_box_contacts"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:hint="search contacts"
                android:background="#beddeb"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/search_online"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="search online"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:background="#5fc0e9"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list_contacts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/topSearchBar"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            tools:listitem="@layout/list_contacts_item">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

list_contact_item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_char_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="a"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#c1292f"
        android:background="#f2f2f2"
        />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:lines="2"
            android:id="@+id/contact_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Abdallah"
            android:padding="5dp"/>




        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/contact_small"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/image_grid_contact"
            android:background="@drawable/contact_offline_pic"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

This gridView is simply a contacts grid where it shows all the contacts available and registered in my network...
On log it shows that it recognizes that there are registered contacts and even it receives a message and if I open the chats tab i see that this listview contact send a message though no contact is appearing in the recycler view...